# Magento admin TooManyRedirects

Tags: python, magento, redirect, magento2

I have written python code to generate access-token and secret from magento. In order to test this locally I have installed a local instance of magento. When I try to access magento admin at http://127.0.0.1/magento/admin/ I am redirected to [http://127.0.0.1/magento/admin/admin/dashboard/index](http://127.0.0.1/magento/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/54b924e44c571047f8a0ffd8ad3ab21237466ce722f3fd7defa046ec30526476/).

I believe there is a redirect loop behind this which is causing issues with execution of my python code as well.

When i try to generate the request token using the following code

```
fetch_response = oauth_session.fetch_request_token(temporary_credentials_request_url)
```

I get an error as follows

> requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects
>   TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.

Please advise how I can fix these redirects

Comment: your links are wrong

Comment: can you explain why you think its wrong?